# sum of contiguous subarray modified

Tags: algorithm

Given a one dimensional array A of size N that may contain both positive and negative integers and an integer K, find the sum of contiguous subarray of numbers which has the largest sum such that no element in the selected array is greater than K. This K changes as we are provided Q queries each containing one integer i.e K.

Example : Let N=5 and Q=6 and array be [1 2 3 4 5] and queries are :

Query 1 : K=5 then chosen subarray is [1,2,3,4,5]. sum of elements = 15.

Query 2 : K=4 then chosen subarray is [1,2,3,4]. sum of elements = 10.

Query 3 : K=3 then chosen subarray is [1,2,3]. sum of elements = 6.

Query 4 : k=2 then chosen subarray is [1,2]. sum of elements = 3.

Query 5 : k=1 then chosen subarray is [1]. sum of elements = 1.

Query 6 : k=0 as There is no element X in array A such that X <= 0. Therefore, answer is "No Solution".

How to answer these queries effieciently ?  Please help as 1 ≤ N,Q ≤ 5*10^5 and -10^ 9 ≤ Ai,K ≤ 10^9

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it linearly.
Here are the steps :

1. initialize `sum=0` and `maximum_sum=0`
2. loop through index 1 to n
   -- if current index value is less than or equal to `K` then add current value to the `sum`. If greater then make `sum=0`
   -- if current sum is greater than `maximum_sum`, update `maximum_sum`
3. print maximum_sum

**Complexity** : **O(n)**

Comment: I believe, you are referring overall complexity **O(n)** for both, time and space. Right @Ali Akber? I think, for space complexity it would be **O(1)**.

Answer (score 2):

Familiarise yourself with [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). In computing the maximum subarray sum, it is necessary to not take into account subarrays which contain elements greater than K. Therefore, in the implementation of the algorithm (take Wikipedia's Python code as an example), for the subarray sum ending at index `I`, where `array[I] > K`, can be considered zero (Ex. prove that it is sufficient and necessary):

```
def max_subarray(A):
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = 0
    for x in A:
        if x > K:
            max_ending_here = 0
        else:
            max_ending_here = max(0, max_ending_here + x)
            max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
    return max_so_far
```

Comment: But K is varying with query per query O(N) is not affordable